# "SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal" when using (?<= lookbehind assertion

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I am getting different errors for this JavaScript code in different browsers:

```
    var updatedate = /(?<=\<meta\ name\=\"updated_at\"\ content\=\")([^\"]*)/;
```

What I want is to find the updated date from the metadata of certain pages. It shows up like this:

```
<meta name="updated_at" content="2018-09-17 11:42 AM">
```

I made it with Sublime to make sure it works and then I tested it on regex101 just to be sure, but Chrome and Mozilla keep giving me that error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `(?<=...)` [lookbehind assertion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) was added to ECMAScript only recently. It's supported by the latest version of Chrome but not Firefox.

Rewrite your regular expression to use a plain group:

```
var updatedate = /(?:\<meta\ name\=\"updated_at\"\ content\=\")([^\"]*)/;
```

You can then extract the timestamp by accessing `data.match(updatedate)[1]`.